# Examples of $\mathcal{C}^r$-diffeomorphisms in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry

My question is very basic, but I've been unable to find a satisfactory answer anywhere. The context: finding two charts on $\mathbb{R}$ that are $\mathcal{C}^r$-compatible but not $\mathcal{C}^{r - 1}$ compatible. In order to do so, I need to find two maps $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that are:

(1) inverses of each other, and
(2) both $(r - 1)$th order (continuously) differentiable but not $r$th order differentiable.

Some possible candidates and why I don't believe they work:

a) $x^{r}\text{sin}(\frac{1}{x})$ is a $\mathcal{C}^{r - 1}$ function, but it's not invertible;

b) Manipulating some piecewise polynomial function with a cusp at some point, ie, integrating the following piecewise function $r - 1$ times:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2 &\text{ for } x \geq 0 \\ x &\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

which does not appear, to me, to have a $\mathcal{C}^{r - 1}$ inverse;

c) Restricting some $\mathcal{C}^{r - 1}$ order function, ie $\lvert x \rvert^{r - 1}$ for $r$ odd to a domain in which finding an inverse wouldn't be a problem (ie, $[0, \infty)$), in which case the function would be class $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$, which I also don't want.

Am I overthinking this? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!